# using unique_ptr<SSL> with OpenSSL v1.1.0

Tags: c++11, openssl

I have some code that manages SSL and SSL_CTX pointers with unique_ptr.

The following code compiles with OpenSSL 1.0.2, but not with OpenSSL 1.1.1:

```
std::unique_ptr<SSL>    m_pSession
```

I include 'openssl/ssl.h', but with OpenSSL 1.1.1 I get the following compile error (using Visual Studio):

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'ssl_st'
```

I have googled a little and it seems that the later version of OpenSSL does not provide the real declaration of `ssl_st` anywhere?  What would be the solution to this?

Comment: Just noting that this question and answer also apply to other opaque OpenSSL types (X509, EVP_PKEY, etc).

The default_deleter implementation needs to know the full size of the structs to call free correctly, but a customer deleter can delegate releasing the target to the relevant OpenSSL APIs.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of the OpenSSL forum I got to the following solution.

Defined a custom deleter for unique_ptr:

```
struct SslDeleter {
    void operator()(SSL *_p)
    {
        SSL_shutdown(_p);
        SSL_free(_p);
    }

    void operator()(SSL_CTX *_p)
    {
        SSL_CTX_free(_p);
    }
};
```

Use a typedef to easily work with the smart pointers:

```
using UniqueSslPtr = std::unique_ptr<SSL, SslDeleter>;
```

and

```
using UniqueCtxPtr = std::unique_ptr<SSL_CTX, SslDeleter>;
```

The custom deleter works for `SSL` and `SSL_CTX` and should also work for `shared_ptr`.